# How to make Javascript object from JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, object

How to make a JSON string into a javascript object. I am trying to convert the following string into JSON Object like this that is getting from the server

JSON String:

```
["{"title":"Admin Dhaka","href":"#0","dataAttrs":[],"data":["{\"title\":\"BNS HAJI MOHSIN\",\"href\":\"#0\",\"dataAttrs\":[\"{\\\"title\\\":\\\"id\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"51\\\"}\"]}","{\"title\":\"BNS ISSA KHAN\",\"href\":\"#1\",\"dataAttrs\":[\"{\\\"title\\\":\\\"id\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"1\\\"}\"]}","{\"title\":\"BNT KHADEM\",\"href\":\"#2\",\"dataAttrs\":[\"{\\\"title\\\":\\\"id\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"6\\\"}\"]}","{\"title\":\"BN DOCKYARD\",\"href\":\"#3\",\"dataAttrs\":[\"{\\\"title\\\":\\\"id\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"13\\\"}\"]}","{\"title\":\"BNT SEBAK\",\"href\":\"#4\",\"dataAttrs\":[\"{\\\"title\\\":\\\"id\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"7\\\"}\"]}","{\"title\":\"Naval Aviation\",\"href\":\"#5\",\"dataAttrs\":[\"{\\\"title\\\":\\\"id\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"89\\\"}\"]}","{\"title\":\"BNS SAIKAT\",\"href\":\"#6\",\"dataAttrs\":[\"{\\\"title\\\":\\\"id\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"40\\\"}\"]}","{\"title\":\"BNS Novojatra\",\"href\":\"#9\",\"dataAttrs\":[\"{\\\"title\\\":\\\"id\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"119\\\"}\"]}","{\"title\":\"BNS SHAH AMANAT\",\"href\":\"#10\",\"dataAttrs\":[\"{\\\"title\\\":\\\"id\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"11\\\"}\"]}"]}"]
```

As an example, I have given one object in the above code actually the Array is a list of Objects like this

```
[obj1, obj2....]
```

I tryed as follows:

```
var arr = '<?php echo !empty($treeView) ? $treeView : "[]"; ?>';
    arr = JSON.parse(arr);
    console.log(arr);
```

Getting the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 4
```

PHP Code:

```
function ship_by_area_zone(){

        $area_list = [];
        $ship_list = [];
        $zone = $this->utilities->findAllByAttributeWithOrderBy("bn_navyadminhierarchy", array("ADMIN_TYPE" => 1, "ACTIVE_STATUS" => 1), "CODE");
        $area = $this->utilities->findAllByAttributeWithOrderBy("bn_navyadminhierarchy", array("ADMIN_TYPE" => 2, "ACTIVE_STATUS" => 1), "CODE");


        // area wise ship
        foreach ($area as $key=>$value)
        {
            $row = $this->db->query("select * from bn_ship_establishment where AREA_ID = $value->ADMIN_ID and ACTIVE_STATUS = 1 order by CODE asc")->row();
            if($row)
            {
                $dataAttrs = array();
                $dataAttrs['title'] = 'id';
                $dataAttrs['data'] = $row->SHIP_ESTABLISHMENTID;
                $dataAttrs = json_encode($dataAttrs);

                $ship_row = array();
                $ship_row['title'] = $row->NAME;
                $ship_row['href'] = "#$key"; //"#1"
                $ship_row['dataAttrs'] = [$dataAttrs];
                $ship_list[] = json_encode($ship_row);
            }
        }

        // zone wise area
        foreach ($zone as $key=>$value)
        {

            $row = $this->db->query("select * from bn_navyadminhierarchy where ACTIVE_STATUS = 1 and PARENT_ID = $value->ADMIN_ID order by CODE asc")->row();
            if($row)
            {
                $area_row = array();
                $area_row['title'] = $row->NAME;
                $area_row['href'] = "#$key";
                $area_row['dataAttrs'] = [];
                $area_row['data'] = $ship_list;
                $area_list[] = json_encode($area_row);
            }
        }

        return json_encode($area_list);
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `["{"title":"` is malformed JSON. Try using `json_encode` instead

Comment: Try usng JSON.parse(),

var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');

Comment: Your JSON is not validated. Please validate the JSON from here: https://jsonlint.com/

and use `JSON.parsey()` to convert JSON to Object.

Comment: How you are generating this JSON?

Comment: I am making JSON Like this  return json_encode([$area_list]); @SamiAhmedSiddiqui

Comment: @BabluAhmed Please remove `[]` under the `json_encode()`

Comment: I have updated the question @SamiAhmedSiddiqui

Comment: @BabluAhmed Please update the JSON in the Question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the json string you have there is invalid. You can check free online to validate the json. Once you have a valid json, you can use JSON.parse() to convert it to JSONObject

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `json_encode` in your PHP:

```
var arr = '<?php echo json_encode(!empty($treeView) ? $treeView : "[]"); ?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// converting a simple javascript object to JSON object
 my_details =  
                {
                   "name"  : "SL",
                   "age "  : "30" ,
                   "photo" : "imgMe.jpg"
                }
my_details_in_json = JSON.stringify(my_details);

// "{"name":"SL","age ":"30","photo":"imgMe.jpg"}" --> my_details_in_json
```